Flutter: Retrying connection due to "SocketException: The semaphore timeout period has expired"
I am working on a Flutter desktop(windows) application that communicates with a server over a socket connection. I'm encountering the following error intermittently when trying to establish a connection:
23:30:11 208ms | Retrying connection (2/5): SocketException: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
(OS Error: The semaphore timeout period has expired, errno = 121), address = 35.152.54.92, port = 62201
Details:
Port: 62201
Retry Count: Occurs during retries, e.g., Retrying connection (2/5)
What I Have Tried:
Checked Server Availability: Verified that the server is online and reachable.
Increased Timeout Settings: Tried increasing the timeout settings to 1 or 2 minutes in the socket connection, but the issue persists.
Network Connection: Verified network stability on the client side. No major issues detected.
Environment:
Flutter Version: [Add your Flutter version here]
Platform: Desktop
Network Type: Ethernet/wifi
What could be causing this semaphore timeout issue?
How can I handle or prevent this error in my Flutter application?
Are there specific socket configurations or best practices to avoid such timeouts?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
